# Sometimes apollo query doesn't occur; I am forced to exit app and reopen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-apollo, apollo-client, hasura

Hi I am using Apollo / Hasura in my React Native application. I am getting an error where sometimes, the query just doesn't occur.

This typically happens when I go back on the app after not using for it an extended period of time (i.e. a couple hours).

When I reboot the app (deleting the app and reopening), the issue usually goes away. Does this mean that there is some caching problem that I need to resolve?

I have tried multiple Apollo queries to resolve this issue. I initially set up an Apollo client with client.query(...) to get the query results. Now, I am using useLazyQuery hook.

In both instances, the query just doesn't complete, leading to infinite loading.

Note, it often works. It just sometimes doesn't. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is?